# Comparing String in Query vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that i am working on.

Following is the scenario

In DB i have a table where 1 code has 4 to 5 variances

1. **DBM***3**1234
2. AGDBM***F**1234
3. AG**M***4**5678
4. AGDBM***5**9872

now i have a text box in winform having a value AGDBMH1R3SR1234.

I want to search the closest match in the DB from the above 4 rows. In above case it is no 1.

I have tried the following

Using string compare in vb.net 
In MSSQL i have used Like Operator but it picks up all the variants.

I highly appreciate your guidance.

Thanks,

Comment: In case of `LIKE`, didn't `where string LIKE 'DBM%'` work?

Comment: Also, how do you say that 1 is the closest match? 1,2 and 4 contain `DBM` as well right?

Comment: The second string has 9 matching characters, the first one has just seven. Why the best match is the number 1?

Comment: I think that the best is to compart a part of first caracters (3 caracter for exemple)  where left(yourvariableDB,3) like '%left(youtext.text,3)"